# fetch name from collection view cell while clicking on checkbox

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview

I have name and image in collection view cell. I want to fetch names which I've selected on clicking checkbox in that particular cell. How do I do this??

**Below is my code in collection view**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: str1+self.nameArr [indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))
    cell.lblName.text = self.nameArr [indexPath.row]
    cell.lblTime.text = self.timeArr [indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

**Here's my cell file:**

```
    class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTime: UILabel!

    var tickCheck:Bool = false

    @IBAction func btnCheck(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if tickCheck == false
        {
            checkButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
            tickCheck = true
        }

        else
        {
            checkButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
            tickCheck = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your CollectionView**

```
class collectionVC: UIViewController,CellDelegate {
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
   {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: str1+self.nameArr [indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))
    cell.lblName.text = self.nameArr [indexPath.row]
    cell.lblTime.text = self.timeArr [indexPath.row]
    cell.checkButton.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.delegateCell = self
     cell.indexPath = indexPath
    return cell
}
//Mark:- Did tap cell
func didTapCell(index: IndexPath){
  let name = self.nameArr[index.item]
   print("Your name >> \(name)")
  }
}
```

**Collection Cell**

```
protocol CellDelegate: class {
    func didTapCell(index: IndexPath)
}
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTime: UILabel!
     var delegateCell:CellDelegate?
   var indexPath:IndexPath?
    var tickCheck:Bool = false

    @IBAction func btnCheck(_ sender: Any)
    {
        delegateCell?.didTapCell(index: indexPath!)
        if tickCheck == false
        {
            checkButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
            tickCheck = true
        }

        else
        {
            checkButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
            tickCheck = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error in Collection File at: delegateCell?.didTapCell(index: IndexPath).
error is: Cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath.Type' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'

Comment: error is gone but, func didTapCell(index: IndexPath) in CollectionView file is not called. I've put a debugger at that method but, method is not called.